# How to get duplicated values in a data frame when the column is a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good morning!

I have a data frame with several columns. One of this columns, data, has lists as content. Below I show a little example (id is just an example with random information):

```
df = 
   id  data
0   a  [1, 2, 3]
1   h  [3, 2, 1]
2  bf  [1, 2, 3]
```

What I want is to get rows with duplicated values in column data, I mean, in this example, I should get rows 0 and 2, because the values in its column data are the same (list [1, 2, 3]). However, this can't be achieved with `df.duplicated(subset = ['data'])` due to list is an unhashable type.

I know that it can be done getting two rows and comparing data directly, but my real data frame can have 1000 rows or more, so I can't compare one by one.

Hope someone knows it!

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: list is not hashable, so you cann't compare `list1 == list2`. You can turn your `data` into `tuple`.

Comment: Why not stringify the elements of the column, then compare strings?

Comment: `df[df['data'].map(str).duplicated(keep=False)]` this will not change your default types

Comment: Thanks you all! I'm using @dkritz solutions and works fine! I think Quang's solution works in the same way too. And Yo_Chris, thanks you too, however I just want to get duplicates rows, I don't care about the column data really. Tanks again!

Comment: please could you check my solution?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, We can create a new DataFrame from `df['data']` and then check with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

You can use:

```
m = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].tolist()).duplicated(keep=False)
```

---

```
df.loc[m]
```

---

```
   id       data
0   a  [1, 2, 3]
2  bf  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding on Quang's comment:*

Try

```
In [2]: elements = [(1,2,3), (3,2,1), (1,2,3)] 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(elements) 
   ...: df                                                                      
Out[2]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  1
2  1  2  3

In [3]: # Add a new column of tuples 
   ...: df["new"] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1) 
   ...: df                                                                      
Out[3]: 
   0  1  2        new
0  1  2  3  (1, 2, 3)
1  3  2  1  (3, 2, 1)
2  1  2  3  (1, 2, 3)

In [4]: # Remove duplicate rows (Keeping the first one) 
   ...: df.drop_duplicates(subset="new", keep="first", inplace=True) 
   ...: df                                                                      
Out[4]: 
   0  1  2        new
0  1  2  3  (1, 2, 3)
1  3  2  1  (3, 2, 1)

In [5]: # Remove the new column if not required 
   ...: df.drop("new", axis=1, inplace=True) 
   ...: df                                                                      
Out[5]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  1
```